# SUMPRODUCT with 3 criterias including date

Tags: excel, criteria, sumproduct

I've been trying to come up with a formula to sum a specific amount.

It has 3 criterias: 1st is an account number: column A; 2nd is a Cost Center number: column C; and 3rd is a date from line i1 to T1 (eg.:i1= jan/2020; t1=dez/2020).

The dates are formated with "date" type: mar/12 on both sheets.

The date on the formula refers to a specific cell $F$2 in order for me to just comeback there, type the month that i want and it automatically calculates the values while taking into account the other criterias.

This is the formula i adapted from some research.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Sheet2!$A:$A=Sheet1!$C20)*(Sheet2!$C:$C=Sheet1!$H3)*(Sheet2!$I$1:$T$1=Sheet1!$F2)*(Sheet2!$I$2:$T$635)
```

This formula currently gives back 0  instead of the value pretended (which is ~631)

Here are 2 prntscreens as form of sample, i hope it helps.

[Sheet1 with formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jq1Ko.png)

[Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXS2u.png)

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe, [edit] your question and post some sample data

Comment: most likely your dates are not true dates and are instead text that look like dates.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, i'll try to post some sample data to further explain my problem

Comment: @ScottCraner both dates on both sheets are formatted with date category. Though cell F2 is refering to a date, it is also formatted with date category. If the problem derives from the dates, which i also suspect, i can't find out why.

Comment: the title bar of a table cannot be true dates but are text that look like dates.  You can format them however you want, it will not change that they are text and not dates.

Comment: @ScottCraner I see. Thank you for your feedback, I'll take a look into that and make changes accordingly.